# Setting the selected options in a multiselect programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiselect on which I want to select some options on page load. The options will be selected using jQuery or javascript according to values of the options. Those values are stored in a variable as a string - exmaple below. What would be the logic to select those options?

```
var values = "1,3,5";
```

Answer (score 8):

here is the example code:

```
var items = "1,3,5";
$.each(items.split(','), function(idx, val) {
    $("select option[value='"+val+"']").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

and here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ftte4/

Comment: You should use `.prop("selected", true)` for jQuery >= 1.6.